# Place AutoComplete Prediction

Tags: xamarin.android, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I am getting no response. What am i missing?
Can anyone give me an idea on it. Having error.

```
        IPlacesClient placesClient = PlacesApi.CreateClient(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);
        PlacesApi.Initialize(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, "********API KEY***************");  
        var token = AutocompleteSessionToken.NewInstance();
        var request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.InvokeBuilder()
            .SetSessionToken(token)
            .SetTypeFilter(TypeFilter.Establishment)
            .SetCountry("US")
            .SetQuery("Ind")
            .Build();
        Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> task = placesClient.FindAutocompletePredictions(request);
```

Comment: Adding Google AutoComplete, you will need your own valid Google API and project setup via the Google Developers Console. I do't see where  is your API key, You can get many info by Google search.

Comment: API key is added. I have edited my query. In google

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/blob/master/Android/GooglePlaces/samples/PlacesSample/MainActivity.cs

You were in the right way.
You must add an Action to your task.

```
task.AddOnSuccessListener(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, this);
task.AddOnFailureListener(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, this);
```

Then, add code to each one of this Actions

```
public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
{
  //Do something
}
public void OnFailure(Java.Lang.Exception e)
{
  //Failed
}
```

Remember to implement IOnSuccessListener, IOnFailureListener and IOnCompleteListener